# .htaccess mask - SEO

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Looking to put the following into my htaccess file:

```
 User visits http://mysite.com/test/test/123
 User is actually visiting http://mysite.com/test/index.php?q=123
```

I have seen it done before but I can't figure it out. The user is **not** supposed to see that they are visiting the second url. This is particularly useful for SEO. Can anyone help me on this one?

**Updated Code for Answer:**

```
Options -Multiviews
rewriterule ^test\/([a-zA-Z]+)\/([0-9]+)$ test\/index\.php?id=$3  [L]
```

*Note: The Options -Multiviews is needed for GoDaddy hosting to enable mod_rewrite.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure mod_rewrite is on:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^test/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)\.html$ test.php?id=$2
```

Comment: This works in theory, the actual code that was necessary I have posted above. Thanks for the mod_rewrite bit, what I had wasn't working because of that.

Answer (score 0):

Double test

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test/test/([^/]*)$ /test/index.php?q=$1 [L]
```

Single test

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test/([^/]*)$ /test/index.php?q=$1 [L]
```